# How to force Spring to execute read queries with transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

So I run into the '[No EntityManager with actual transaction available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948383/understanding-spring-and-no-entitymanager-with-actual-transaction-available)' problem, and thanks to that I realized that Spring is executing my `SELECT` queries without transactions.

Since some people warn against this practice (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451935/cannot-reliably-process-persist-call-why-this-happen#comment54690670_33451935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operation)), how do I tell Spring to always use transactions?

**EDIT**

Judging from the answers that I got so far, I think that my question was not clear enough. So I don't have the 'No EntityManager with actual transaction available' anymore. I fixed that, but when I did have the problem, it was only for `persist` and `merge` operations, things like `find` were working, so that made me realize that Spring is only creating transactions for write operations. What I want now, is to force it to also create transactions for read-only operations.

Comment: How about annotating method with `@Transactional`?

Comment: @pmverma My DAO classes are already annotated

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you have an web application:*
An other solution, would been using the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`

From its JavaDoc:

> This filter makes JPA EntityManagers available via the current thread, which will be autodetected by transaction managers. It is suitable for service layer transactions via TransactionManager or JtaTransactionManager **as well as for non-transactional read-only execution.**

So just add this lines to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I want to keep the transaction granularity at DAO level. Furthermore, I'm not looking for a solution to the `no transaction available` problem, but to force Spring to use transactions with `SELECT` queries.

Comment: You need to put ONE! `@Transactional` annotation arround the code that execute every sql-query. And pay attention to layzloading. - So if you use lazy loading and want to have every query in the same transaction, then attaching the `@Transactional` only at the DAO layer will likly not work.

Comment: Thanks, but my DAO classes are annotated with `@Transactional`. I don't want lazy loading, that's not the issue. The issue is that the no transaction available made me realize that Spring is not creating transactions for `SELECT` queries, and I want to force it to create them. Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

If your code code contains a @Transactional and there is no transation open, It maybe means that you lack a TransactionManager you have to declare it like this :

```
<!-- Enables declarative transaction management with @Transactional annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

(change the transactionManager Class according to your persistence technology here is for hibernate 3)

Comment: So what make you think that your select is executed without transaction ?

Comment: That I was getting that `No Entity Manager...` error only for `persist` and `merge`, not for `find`. I could happily get results from `SELECT` queries.